# Negate and (greatly) simplify the following statement:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$= \lnot(p \land (p \lor q)) \land \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q)$

$= \lnot p \lor ( \lnot p \land \lnot q) \land (p \land q)$

$= \lnot p$

Is my logic correct? I know that $p \land p$ is just $p$ but does $(\lnot p \land \lnot q) \land (p \land q)$ cancel the whole thing out?

Comment: last part of the second line is wrong. It is not $p\land q$ but it must be $p\lor q$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lnot(p \land (p \lor q)) \land \lnot(\lnot p \land \lnot q)$$

is equal to

$$\lnot p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot q)) \land (p \lor q)$$

is equal to (by absorption law)

$$\lnot p \land (p \lor q)$$

is equal to (by distributive law)

$$(\lnot p \land p) \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$

is equal to

$$Contradiction \lor (\lnot p \land q)$$

is equal to

$$(\lnot p \land q)$$.

Answer (score 1):

$
\begin{equation}
\phantom{\equiv}\neg(p\wedge(p\vee q))\wedge\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\\
\equiv\neg p\vee(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\wedge\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\\
\equiv \neg p
\end{equation}
$

because $(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\wedge\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)\equiv a\wedge\neg a\equiv\operatorname{False}$, where $a\equiv \neg p\wedge\neg q$